# Testing Android In App Billing purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

i am new to in-app purchase, i successfully integrated it in application,now i want to test in app-purchase, as per documentation we have to deploy it into alpha-or beta channel for testing in-app purchases, but whether any code change required for testing in app purchase..please provide guideline or example on how to test in-app Purchases.. any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have to upload app on beta or alpha testing mode in playstore and  also add in app billings. After 6 or 8 hours you can  test your in app purchases

Comment: @ Neeraj Sharma any code change required?

Comment: no. your  app must be published in alpha or beta mode . and add in app billing from playstore account

Comment: ok i will test it thank you so much for help

Comment: one more thing login your playstore with that id you adding in  testing email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer THIS:

```
I refere this link thats why i suggest you for in app purchase Testing inapp test link


 http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_Tutorial
```

Comment: Link is too old now. do you know a method to test subscription without waiting for days pending? tx